# Vuetify theme in dynamic Vue Component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

If I dynamically create a Vue component (using Vue.extend and calling the constructor) it doesn't know about the Vuetify theming. How do I inject Vuetify into a new dynamically created component?

Comment: You can not inject the whole Vuetify library inside a single, dynamically created component.

Comment: Is there any way to tell a new Vue Component about Vuetify then? How do I make a new Component reactive so I can change the theme with Vuetify?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to not dynamically create the component but instead add the component to an array and use v-for in the body to iterate over them. The other trick with using Muuri was to wait for the next tick so Vuetify could mount the component before we add it to the Muuri grid.

Template:

```
 <div class="grid">
  <div
    class="item"
    v-for="(def, index) in definitions"
    :key="index"
    ref="gridItem"
  >
    <div class="item-content">
      <CosmosScreen :definition="def" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
import CosmosScreen from './CosmosScreen'
import * as Muuri from 'muuri'

export default {
  components: {
    CosmosScreen
  },
  data() {
    return {
      grid: null
      definitions: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.grid = new Muuri('.grid', {
      dragEnabled: true
    })
  },
  methods: {
    showScreen() {
      this.definitions.push("Screen Definition")
      this.$nextTick(function() {
        this.grid.add(this.$refs.gridItem[this.$refs.gridItem.length - 1])
      })
    }
  }
}
```

The CosmosScreen component details aren't important here but it takes a string and dynamically creates a screen of Vuetify widgets.

Comment: We could not guess from your original question that you are using Muuri and CosmosScreen. Now the situation is more clear.